# Как создать всплывающее окно

Tags: java, android

Как создать всплывающее окно в Android при нажатии на слово? И что бы была возможность добавить кнопки действия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: с кнопками]

Comment: [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) это